# Model follow/unfollow button in Android

Tags: android, button, layout, interface, drawable

How would I model a follow/unfollow button in Android? Is [State List Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) what I am looking for? How can define the two different states?

Comment: StateListDrawable only has predefined logical states (pressed, focus) that have a meaning for the platform. You'd need to implement your buttons state manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly dependant on the visual effect you want to achieve.

First, the basics (I assume you already know this): you need a `Button`, `setOnClickListener()` for a listener that toggles the state, and someplace to save this (either a local database, your own server, or whatever).

The easiest, least attractive way, would be to just switch the text on the button whenever the "follow" state changes (with `setText()` in the click listener).

A possible improvement would be to have different button backgrounds, so that the appearance also changes (say, from a grey star to a yellow one). For this, you just need to call `setBackground()` in the click listener.

For a fancier effect, you can use a [`TransitionDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) to crossfade this change. `startTransition()` and `reverseTransition()` would then be used for the two state changes. For example:

```
Drawable d1 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.follow_button);
Drawable d2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.unfollow_button);
final TransitionDrawable followDrawable = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] { d1, d2 });
final int transitionDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

button.setBackground(followDrawable);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (!mFollowing)
        {
            mFollowing = true;
            followDrawable.startTransition(transitionDuration);
        }
        else
        {
            mFollowing = false;
            followDrawable.reverseTransition(transitionDuration);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to save your state. Whether it is "follow" or "unfollow". Where to save depends on your application logic.

Then, according to the current state, you can update the appearance of the button. What StateListDrawable does is, it update the background of your button based on the state whether it is "focused", "selected", etc.

You can use State List Drawable as a background of your button. Then, if the current state is "follow", you set your button as selected (vis Button.setSelected(true)). If the current state is "unfollow", it will be normal. (Button.setSelected(false).

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_for_follow" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_for_unfollow" />
```

Something like this. In above example, if you set that drawable file as the background of your button, it would use "bg_for_follow" when the button state is "selected" and it would use "bg_for_unfollow" when the butotn state is normal.

Hope that could help.

Comment: A state list drawable seems like a really poor fit for this.

Comment: @matiash, Then, can u suggest a better ? Or at least can you explain me why it is a poor fit ?

Comment: Pretty much for the reasons that @Dadou hinted at. These state flags (selected, pressed, &c) have meaning for the framework, and can be changed by it (for example, if placed inside a `ListView`). You wouldn't want the button to change follow-unfollow by itself.

Comment: Oh. I see. Yes. The state of the button could be interfered by the framework itself such as ListView or by the user interaction. Thanks. I didn't check on @Dadou's hint. :)